# The header titles not displaying properly when the report is output in csv format

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008

I have a reporting services 2008 r2 report that I output to csv format, but the problem is that the headers for the columns are displaying like 'FirstName' when I want it to display like 'First Name' Is there a way to change that?

Answer (score 0):

The csv output uses the control name for the output textbox. If you change the control name this will update. (I'm not sure that you can use spaces in control names though).